# Any way to stop apt-get upgrade downgrading npm to version 2?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, node.js, npm

I installed nodejs 4 on Ubuntu 14.04 using node's official PPA, [as described here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions). It seems like npm v2 is the default so I upgraded npm to v3 using itself (`npm update --global`). Version 3 is required by the software I am deploying.

Everything is fine until I run regular security updates etc. using `apt-get update`/`upgrade` and npm gets consistently downgraded to v2.

Is there any way to prevent npm global packages (specifically npm itself) being altered by apt-get?

Some config files in case useful:

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe

# /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list 
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x trusty main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x trusty main
```

Comment: Ah, one more thing, what do you get for `apt-cache policy nodejs`?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more searching I found this [github thread](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/114) which seems to suggest you are going to need to do some pinning.  I suggest you try adding creating the file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/nodejs` with the below contents as suggested in that issue.

```
Package: *
Pin: origin deb.nodesource.com
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

You can use the `apt-cache policy nodejs` command before and after configuring pinning to verify that it changes the priorities.